# What is the difference between EIGHT_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC and EIGHT_LEVEL in xkb symbols files?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

The title says it all. What is the difference between the two and when should I choose one over another when creating a custom eight level layout?

For context, here is in an excerpt from `partial alphanumeric_keys xkb_symbols "T3"` from `de` xkb symbols file.

```
    key.type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC";
    key <AB01> { [               y,               Y,           U203A,        NoSymbol,           U0292,           U01B7,   guillemotleft,        NoSymbol ] };
    key <AB02> { [               x,               X,  guillemotright,        NoSymbol, doublelowquotemark, singlelowquotemark, guillemotright,   NoSymbol ] };
    key <AB03> { [               c,               C,       copyright,        NoSymbol,            cent,       copyright,  Greek_horizbar,        NoSymbol ] };
    key <AB04> { [               v,               V,   guillemotleft,        NoSymbol, leftdoublequotemark, leftsinglequotemark,   U2039,        NoSymbol ] };
    key <AB05> { [               b,               B,           U2039,        NoSymbol, rightdoublequotemark, rightsinglequotemark, U203A,        NoSymbol ] };
    key <AB06> { [               n,               N,          endash,        NoSymbol,           U019E,           U0220,          endash,        NoSymbol ] };
    key <AB07> { [               m,               M,        Greek_mu,        NoSymbol,              mu,       masculine,          emdash,        NoSymbol ] };
    key.type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL";
    key <AB08> { [           comma,       semicolon,           U02BB,        NoSymbol,        ellipsis,        multiply,          dollar,        NoSymbol ] };
    key <AB09> { [          period,           colon,           U200C,        NoSymbol,  periodcentered,        division,      numbersign,        NoSymbol ] };
    key <AB10> { [           minus,      underscore,          hyphen,        NoSymbol,           U0140,           U013F,           U2011,        NoSymbol ] };
```

Comment: The difference is that in the "_ALPHABETIC", the first two columns (unmodified, and shifted), you'll have the *alphabet*.  You can have both groups on the same keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests and looking at the definition of those levels the difference is that the `ALPHABETIC` type locks into the second level with <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd>, while the non `ALPHABETIC` the second level is achieved only while pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

See the following section of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/types/level5`. Only in the `ALPHABETIC` you can find `map[Lock]  = Level2;`, `map[Lock+LevelFive]  = Level6;` and so on...

```ruby
    type "EIGHT_LEVEL" {
    modifiers = Shift+LevelThree+LevelFive;
    map[None] = Level1;
    map[Shift] = Level2;
    map[LevelThree] = Level3;
    map[Shift+LevelThree] = Level4;
    map[LevelFive] = Level5;
    map[Shift+LevelFive] = Level6;
    map[LevelThree+LevelFive] = Level7;
    map[Shift+LevelThree+LevelFive] = Level8;
    level_name[Level1] = "Base";
    level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
    level_name[Level3] = "Alt Base";
    level_name[Level4] = "Shift Alt";
    level_name[Level5] = "X";
    level_name[Level6] = "X Shift";
    level_name[Level7] = "X Alt Base";
    level_name[Level8] = "X Shift Alt";
    };

    type "EIGHT_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC" {
    modifiers = Shift+Lock+LevelThree+LevelFive;
    map[None] = Level1;
    map[Shift] = Level2;
    map[Lock]  = Level2;
    map[LevelThree] = Level3;
    map[Shift+LevelThree] = Level4;
    map[Lock+LevelThree] =  Level4;
    map[Lock+Shift+LevelThree] = Level3;

    map[LevelFive] = Level5;
    map[Shift+LevelFive] = Level6;
    map[Lock+LevelFive]  = Level6;
    map[LevelThree+LevelFive] = Level7;
    map[Shift+LevelThree+LevelFive] = Level8;
    map[Lock+LevelThree+LevelFive] =  Level8;
    map[Lock+Shift+LevelThree+LevelFive] = Level7;

    level_name[Level1] = "Base";
    level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
    level_name[Level3] = "Alt Base";
    level_name[Level4] = "Shift Alt";
    level_name[Level5] = "X";
    level_name[Level6] = "X Shift";
    level_name[Level7] = "X Alt Base";
    level_name[Level8] = "X Shift Alt";
    };
```